# custom Parse error code with localizable.string?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

I am trying to create a custom string for parse's "invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.8.1)" . Here is the code that presents this error code in a custom alert view:

```
       PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord) {
            (user, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil || error == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self)
                }

            } else {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.activityIND.stopAnimating()
                let errorView:String = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! String
                self.failedMessage(errorView)
            }
         }
      }
   }

    func failedMessage(theMessage: String){
        let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: theMessage, closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
        myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
        myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
        myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
        myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
    }
```

now I created a localizable.strings file and added the following string

```
"error" = "something isn't right, check the username and password fields"
```

now I'm almost for sure that is the incorrect format because I've never used localizable strings before, but you get the point. Im trying to disguise that plain "invalid login parameters" message with my custom one. Using my localizable.strings file, how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your other configurations for localisation [have been set up](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)—you would need to do something like this:

```
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord) {
        (user, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil || error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self)
            }

        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.activityIND.stopAnimating()

                if let message = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                    where message = "invalid login parameters" {
                    let localizedMessage = NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "")
                    println(localizedMessage)
                    self.failedMessage(localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just change your line in `Localizable.strings` to:

```
"invalid login parameters" = "something isn't right, check the username and password fields";
```

… noting that it uses the specific Parse error message (as a key) to lookup your *localized* version – and not forgetting the semicolon at the end.

***Caution***: This isn't what I would recommend as the error message provided by Parse is much more susceptible to change, than say—the error code associated. It would be wise to check for that instead, leaving less room for unnecessary maintenance.

Comment: no i can't adjust the message from my alert view, I have to adjust the message according to the specific message in the parameter , hence the line `func failedMessage(theMessage: String)` .. if there is an error in the login then i show the specific message `let errorView:String = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! String` in `self.failedMessage(errorView)`

Comment: so how do i add the `NSLocalizedString"` in my `let errorView:String = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! String` constant

Comment: so in the `where errorCode =` statement, i should put `"invalid login parameters"` ? because thats the error message parse sends out

Comment: I've edited the solution to use the error string instead

Comment: its still giving me "invalid login parameters"

Comment: I've modified the code a bit. Try that and check that the line `println(localizedMessage)` prints out your custom message. Otherwise, it's something wrong with your *localization setup* and I would suggest going through the link I provided or sharing your project so I could have a look.

Comment: yeah its still printing "invalid login parameters" and i read that article prior to asking the question, as far as localization setup, all i did was create a localization.strings file

Comment: I mean was there more to do? and i might add that is literally the only article out that is semi-dated

Comment: The article is still relevant as most of the setup for *localization* is language-agnostic really. If you created it as `localization.strings` and not `Localizable.strings`—then that may be the issue, as the article states:

*"Localizable.strings is the default filename iOS uses for localized text. Resist the urge to name the file something else, otherwise you will have to type the name of your .strings file every time you reference a localized string."*

Comment: If that doesn't help, then I'd suggest sharing your project (you can remove the Parse credentails) on Github so I could have a closer look. Otherwise it's just stabs in the dark.

Comment: Ah shucks—I take it that didn't help either. I would have, but I'm on the clock now :/

Comment: yeah, my file was already named Localizable.strings thats why haha, its cool

Comment: so i deleted the localization file and added it again, this method worked. thanks